# Is editing a post twice counted in total edits as two separate edits?

Tags: support, edits

I recently faced a situation in which I edited the question and formatted the code, and my changes were overridden by OP to previous state as OP added some more content to the question.

So I had to edit the post twice. Now my question is will this be counted as two separate edits or a single one?

Comment: Depends - was the your edit recorded in the post's edit history?

Comment: If [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550892/c-passing-and-using-function-pointers) is the question in question, then no.  Only edits that show in the posts edit history are counted as valid edits, so you have 1 edit here.

Comment: Ohh nice.. You dug into my edit history :) Why is it that it is not count as two valid edits?

Comment: Because you only made 1 edit.  The other edit was lost in an edit race with the OP (based on your description in the question), so wasn't recorded and doesn't exist as far as the system is concerned

Comment: Races here too :( Thanks btw.

Comment: Edit collisions happen all of the time - and usually depends on who clicks "Save Edit" first, although there are cases where a 2nd more significant edit can override a previously submitted edit.  Probably won't be the last time it happens to you.  But generally speaking, if you are concerned about not getting credit for 1 edit (presumably to get one of the editing badges), you are editing for the wrong reasons.

Comment: No not at all worried about getting badges :) Just was curious as it happened to me for the first time. I am here on SO to help people out and participate in a great community and not to get some badges.

Comment: And the reason I was curious is that if making multiple edits to same post are count multiple times then someone can misuse it to get badges. So everything for community.

Comment: @Narenda Only one edit counts towards the badges per post, and edits to your *own* posts do not count towards the badges at all. That issue has already been addressed long ago.